# jQuery UI sortable 'out' not firing whith multiple connected sortables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

When two or more sortables are connected with `connectWith`, the out event doesn't fire when I move the item out of the list (not into another list).

To reproduce, try dragging an item from one of the connected lists away from both lists (not into the other list). 'out' won't fire. Then try the bottom unconnected sortable. It will fire normally.

Is there any way to find out when an item was dragged out of the connected sortables?

Example:

```
Connected lists:
<ul class="connect">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="connect">
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
</ul>

Unconnected list:
<ul class="not-connected">
    <li>seven</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>nine</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(".connect").sortable({
    out: function() {
       console.log("out");   
    },
    connectWith: ".connect"
});

$(".not-connected").sortable({
    out: function() {
       console.log("out");   
    },
});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/751vo8d3/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9335) with `out` and `over` that has since been fixed. I believe you're using a version that has that problem. I've updated the fiddle to use the new version of jQuery UI and seems to be working fine, http://jsfiddle.net/751vo8d3/2/